# RSpec POST changes the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

Rails 3, RSpec 2:

In my rspec test for a controller, I'm using post and pass in some parameters:

```
it "returns a job id" do
  post :new, { :a => 'b'}
  response.status.should == 200
end
```

This works fine and in the controller `params[:a] is 'b'`

However, `request.url` on the controller side is http://localhost/controller?a=b

I don't want to have the parameters in the URL since in a real scenario (outside test) the URL is part of a security signature.

My question is why rspec post adds the parameters to the URL instead of behaving the same way as a POST in a browser (or CURL)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found an answer for this yet, but here is how I managed to solve the problem so my unit tests work: I simple by-pass signature checking when running unit tests. Here is the code:

```
def check_signature
  return if request.host == 'test.host'

  # check signature
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old but I find it strange that you're using post for the :new action. Generally :new shows a form, thus you'd have 'get :new' and in the create test you'd use post, 'post :create, params = {blah: blah}'.

Check your routes to see if your :new action is post or get.

Comment: I take your point. The code in the question is an example. The problem is real!